# TypeError: buy_sell() takes positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python-3.x, function

Line: a = buy_sell(ETH_data)

Type Error: buy_sell() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Background: I'm working on a personal project to create something to visualize buy-sell conditions of traded assets

I appreciate it a million if you can help me out with this.

```
def buy_sell():
        Buy = []
        Sell = []
        flag = -1

        for i in range(0, len(ETH_data)):
                if ETH_data['close'][i] > ETH_data['SMA200'][i] and ETH_data['macdhist'][i] > 0:
                        Sell.append(np.nan)
                        if flag != 1:
                                if ETH_data['close'][i] > ETH_data['EMA20'][i] and ETH_data['macdhist'][i] > 0:
                                        Buy.append(ETH_data['close'][i])
                                        flag = 1
                        else:
                                Buy.append(np.nan)

                elif ETH_data['close'][i] < ETH_data['SMA200'][i] and ETH_data['macdhist'][i] < 0:
                        Buy.append(np.nan)
                        if flag != 0:
                                if ETH_data['close'][i] < ETH_data['EMA20'][i] and ETH_data['macdhist'][i] > 0:
                                        Sell.append(ETH_data['close'][i])
                                        flag = 0
                        else:
                                Sell.append(np.nan)
                else:
                        Buy.append(np.nan)
                        Sell.append(np.nan)
        return (Buy,Sell)


a = buy_sell(ETH_data)
ETH_data['Buy_Signal_Price'] = a[0]
ETH_data['Sell_Signal_Price'] = a[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `buy_sell()` is defined not to get any variable and you are passing `ETH_data` to it.
To solve it you can do either remove the `ETH_data` from the function call like `buy_sell()`
OR
add to the `buy_sell` function a parameter such as `def buy_sell(ETH_data):`.
Probably the second option of `def buy_sell(ETH_data):` is more relevant for your code since there is a useage of `ETH_data` inside the `buy_sell` function.

Comment: You welcome, happy to help. It will be appreciated if you can mark the answer and vote up:)